# can I use Entity Framework when the DBMS-type is not known at build time?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework

I'm developing an application (CRUD WS) that connects to single database that can be Oracle or SQL server and the type is read from configuration file. Can I use EF to implement DAL? Some requirements:

- the tables do not have primary keys and i can't add them.
- C# / .NET 4.0
- all operations are done and committed always directly to database
- all operations are simple CRUD and nothing is cached for reads
- transaction support (one request can deal with multiple tables) -> commit / rollback
- the model has to be built for only 10 tables while db has hundreds of tables
- if db is oracle the tables are divided to table spaces and not all of these 10 tables are in same table space

If I can do this a link or an example would be nice.

I asked this question in other way but I got instantly 2 close-votes so here's my 2nd try.

Comment: Why don't your tables have primary keys?  Can the data model really be that bad?

Comment: I haven't seen your previous question but the reason people vote to close is probably because you ask a rather complicated question which requires some research to answer and the time you spent to ask the question and someone to research for an answer is much longer than the time you would spend on actually trying to conduct an experiment on your own.

Comment: "the tables do not have primary keys and i can't add them." sounds ridiculous for me but I am definitely interested to know if I can use Entity Framework when the DBMS-type is not known at build time.

Comment: tables have "primary keys" as unique indexes that can identified with a naming convention. it seems that one has to have a model for each type of DBMS or at least part of the model (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988177/entity-framework-oracle-and-sql-server-how-to-build-a-database-independent-app)

Comment: It also seem that it does not make sense to use EF in my situation even when I can add the primary keys. Because foreign keys can't be added (0 as FK means no asssociation) I have to create associations where other relationship-end is wrong (1 instead of 0-1) because these columns are not null. In addition the models must be updated by hand when the database changes, which is completely unacceptable. In short: there's too little to gain and too much work keeping 2 models (oracle/sqlserver) up-to-date.