# what is current solution to support both Oracle and SQL dbs in C# application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, ado.net

The application reads from config file that which database type it should use. The tables are basically the same in both types.

For example customers A and C in country X have chosen Oracle. Customers B and D in USA have chose SQL Server. Program accesses only one database which can be either type. The program must be able to handle both. Like with ADO.NET based program using classes like DbConnection instead of OracleConnection or SqlConnection.

The database (naturally in both types) has hundreds of tables existing that each C# application needs to use some subset. The tables cannot be changed.

ADO.NET tried to address this with System.Data namespace but System.Data.OracleClient is deprecated. ODP.NET can replace that but somehow i'm not impressed.

Comment: Entity Framework or NHibernate

Comment: Entity Framework?! At least it didn't work 2 years back. U were supposed to had model for both and it was complete hassle.

Comment: With Code First it shouldn't be a problem... You can select the DB "driver" from the .config file

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers". Voting to close.

Comment: @DavidArno this does not fall in that category. Get a life

Comment: @matti Actually, it kind of does... I will not vote for closing but your response to David was inappropriate.

Comment: Are your database access limited to stored procedures only or does your application generate it's own sql statements and sends them to the database?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I agree. I just hate this nonsense. This has 1 upvote and i star... If I had wrote it differently this wouldn't be closed. That's absolutely ridiculous. Chekc this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988177/entity-framework-oracle-and-sql-server-how-to-build-a-database-independent-app

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I have no application yet. I'm asking for future use. I have database. Previous applications are written with ADO.NET.

Comment: @DavidArno: Guess u're right cause 2nd close vote has arrived. Moreover I'm sorry for my inappropriate comment no matter u're right or wrong. Won't happen again.

Comment: If you can work with only stored procedures then it should be ok to use ADO.Net, just instead of the deprecated `OracleClient` use a 3rd party oracle provider like Microsoft suggests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78381/discussion-between-matti-and-zohar-peled).